# How to Pull Microsoft CRM data and Display on sharepoint page

Tags: c#

I want to know how i will pull Microsoft CRM 4.0 data and display it into Sharepoints Page.

Cann any one suggest some Architecture for this.

And anyon tell me what is the pros and cons when we doing this.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Regards
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

Use the [List Web Part for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=3B6EB884-EC15-4288-A2A3-D0B47E057458&displaylang=en)

Alternatively, you could build your own web part and populate it with data retrieved via the CRM web services or the FilteredViews in the Database.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Use the [CRM Web Part](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20651).
2. Select straight from the CRM defined views within SQL Server.
3. Use the CRM Fetch XML Web Services API.
4. Use the [Advanced Developer Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681559.aspx) in the 4.1.2 SDK that provide LINQ and OData support over the top of your CRM.